How to handle very small dataset in time series forecasting?
I have a dataset of expenses where, i need to predict 5 years ahead with very limited data (10 data only available for 5 years). i need to predict each term in a year, where Jan-Jun (First term) & July-Dec (Second term). i plan to use Prophet but still if the count of data is less or equal to 10, is this model suitable to use? or you have any other suggestions?
Is this type of data suitable for time-series forecasting?
